# How to select a link using its id or its label with the symfony dom crawler?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, domcrawler

Is it possible to select a link using its id or its class with the symfony crawler?

I tried:

```php
$crawler()->selectLink('#return-button')->link();
$crawler()->selectLink('.btn.return')->link();
```

But I have the error:

> InvalidArgumentException: The current node list is empty.

Does the selector only works using the content of the `a` tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it only works with the link text or `alt` attribute if your link is an image.

The `filter()` method uses the `CssSelector` component to transform a selector into an XPath expression and then calls `filterRelativeXPath()` just as `selectLink()` does, so they return the same type and you should be able to just call

```
$crawler->filter('#return-button')->link();
```

In case of a class selector that returns multiple matches, since `link()` only works on the first node, you'll need to call `links()` instead:

```
$crawler->filter('.btn.return')->links();
```

Answer (score 1):

I dont think so:

```
public selectLink ( string $value ) : Crawler
```

where the $value is a string that is the link text:

[symfony.component.domcrawler/Crawler/selectLink](https://hotexamples.com/examples/symfony.component.domcrawler/Crawler/selectLink/php-crawler-selectlink-method-examples.html)

But you can try:

```
$crawler->filter('body')->children('a.lorem')->attr('href'); //if you need the link
```

or may, this is work with ids:

```
$crawler->filter('body')->children('a@foo');
```

You should figure out to yourself, if check this:

[symfony/components/dom_crawler](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$myLink = $crawler->filter('#return-button')->text();
$myLink = $crawler->filter('.btn.return')->text();
```

This will return the link or button text, and then:

```
$crawler()->selectLink($myLink)->link();
```

This is indeed better than selecting links by text. Best of luck :-)

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Sadly it does not work, I suppose because there is an icon tag in my link and the crawler is not able to `selectLink` when it contains HTML.