# How to select a link by its label containing non breaking spaces using the symfony dom crawler?

Tags: php, html, symfony, domcrawler

I have a link:

```html
<a
    id="return-button"
    href="{{ path('user_list') }}"
    class="btn btn-secondary">
    <i class="icon ion-md-arrow-back"></i>&nbsp;Back to the list
</a>
```

I try to use it in a Test. For this purpose, I select it by its label:

```php
self::$client->getCrawler()
             ->selectLink('Back to the list')
             ->link();
```

But the test throws an error:

> InvalidArgumentException: The current node list is empty.

It's because of the `&nbsp;` in the link label. If I replace it with a simple space, the dow crawler is able to select it.

How can I select this link without removing the non breaking space in it?

Comment: have you tried with ->selectLink('&nbsp;Back to the list') or  have you tried with ->selectLink("\x20Back to the list") ?

Comment: I tried the two of them and sadly none of them work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select a link using its id or its label with the symfony dom crawler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57397284/how-to-select-a-link-using-its-id-or-its-label-with-the-symfony-dom-crawler)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in this issue: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/33062, this behavior is a bug due to the XPath engine used by Symfony.

Currently, to avoid the problem, we can specify the non breaking space in the DOM crawler selector by doing:

```php
self::$client->getCrawler()
             ->selectLink("\xc2\xa0Back to the list")
             ->link();
```

Mind the double quotes instead of the simple ones.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use this syntax:

{{ ' Back to the list'|raw }}

Or this one :

{{ ' Back to the list' }}